# Access Activity WebView from Class

Tags: android

why this is return null:

```
public class ReadPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    ReadPage activityRead;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_page);
        ReadPage = this;

        new LoaderController(readPage);
    }
```

and the LoaderController:

```
 public LoaderController(ReadPage activity) {
        ObservableWebView wv = (ObservableWebView) activity.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("www.google.com");
    }
}


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings.....ObservableWebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference
```

ok i understand, but WHY NULL SINCE im passing the real Activity?

Comment: that might be due to your web view is not initialized properly.

Comment: try like this-       new LoaderController((ReadPage)this);